# Accessing iframe HTML DOM with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have seen a few threads concerning accessing the HTML DOM inside an iFrame with javascript and/or jquery, but these are not working for me. Here is the sample I am testing:

Here is the HTML file iframe.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
body1
<div id="mydiv" style="background-color: red">
   div text red bg
   <h1 style="background-color: gray">IFRAME gray bg </h1>
</div>
body2

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the test code w/javascript & jquery tests:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="myframe" src="iframe.html"></iframe>

<div id="demo">div area</div>

<p>Click the button to change the iframe color.</p>
<button id="jq_btn" >exec jquery</button>
<button id="js_btn" onclick="myFunction()" >exec javascript</button>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jq_btn").click(function(){
    $("body").css( "background-color", "yellow" );
    $("body").css( "color", "blue" );
    $("div").css( "background-color", "orange" );
    $( "iframe" ).contents().filter( "body" ).css( "background-color", "blue" );
    $( "iframe" ).contents().find( "body" ).css( "background-color", "blue" );
    $("#myframe").contents().filter( "h1" ).css( "color", "green" );
    $("#myframe").contents().find( "h1" ).css( "color", "green" );
  });
});

function myFunction() {
  //alert('myFunction');
  var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
  var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  elmnt.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But neither of these sample succeed in accessing the iframe contents.
The javascript sample seems to be failing accessing the 'document' object in instruction `iframe.contentWindow.document`

Can someone advise what I'm doing wrong in either of these cases?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Do  iframe and page share same origin (domain, protocol subdomain etc)? What is specific error you see?

Comment: You have zero access to iframe dom

Comment: @GetSet Not true if same origin https://plnkr.co/edit/W01O5tXB9ThdATTS?preview

Comment: Makes sense, i followed link @charlietfl

Comment: Thanks [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl), I put both of the above samples in the same directory and launch the one with the javascript/jquery. I then press the button to execute 'exec jquery' and it colors the things outside of the iframe, but not inside.

I tried the [plnkr.co/edit/W01O5tXB9ThdATTS?preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/W01O5tXB9ThdATTS?preview) on my local system, but the "Iframe heading" does not turn red.